# lapply on a list of list not working in R

Tags: r

I have

```
typeof(A)
>"list"
typeof(A[1])
>"list"
typeof(A[[1]])
>"double"
```

And when I run

```
A=lapply(A,unlist)
typeof(A[1])
>"list"
```

The result seems to be the same. Yet if I run

```
B=unlist(A[1])
typeof(B)
"double"
```

Please help me understand this behaviour. Why is there a difference between the two? Should lapply not apply the function to each element of the list? Than A[i] should be like B?

Comment: if `A` is a list then `A[1`] will automatically be a list. It does NOT imply that you are dealing with a list of lists. On the other hand, if `typeof(A[[1]])` returned "list" then we would be. The function `lapply` should be thought of as a loop over `A[[i]]` where `i` is the range of `1:length(A)`.  Note:  I didn't say over `A[i]`.

Comment: @42- I see, if A is a list, A[i] is always a list... I did not know this. So I in fact, do not have a list of lists, but a list of vectors? Can you please elaborate on why A[i] is always a list? I will accept your answer if you do. Thank you

Comment: The "[" function applied to a list always returns a sublist. A sublist is still a list. If length A == 1 then A[1] == A modulo the possibility of missing attributes and modulo the fact that the `==` operator will not accept these as arguments.

Answer (score -2):

`lapply` actually returns a list as its output. It applies a function to several elements, and returns each output as an element of a list.

For what it's worth, `A[[1]]` being of type double actually tells you you have a list of doubles. The `[[ ]]` references elements of a list, the `[]` references elements of a vector. So by asking for  `A[1]` you're getting the first element as a list, by asking for `A[[1]]` you're getting the first element de-listed.

I suspect what you want is just `unlist(A)`. That will return each element of A as an element in a single vector. In your case A is a list of doubles. So hopefully that's what you want.

Take this example

```
test = list(list(5), list(3), list(1))
> test #Notice this is a list of lists, each containing one element
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 5


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 3


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 1

> test[2] #Notice this has exported the second element as a new list with one element
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 3

> test[[2]] #Notice this has exported the second element not as a list, so now we have one listed instead of two nested lists.
[[1]]
[1] 3

lapply(test, unlist) #This returns a list of element rather than a list of lists
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 1

unlist(lapply(test, unlist)) #This returns a vector of elements by unlisting the list of elements we created in the previous step
[1] 5 3 1
```

I hope that clears up some of the behaviour :)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have a list where each element is a list with one vector inside. I want to get a list with vectors. So that A is still a list, but its elements are not lists that contain a vector, but the vectors. If I do unlist(A), i just get one long vector.

Comment: Then do you want `unlist(lapply(A,unlist))`? So you unlist each element to get a list of elements, then unlist that list of elements?

Comment: If A is `list(B=1:10, C=10:29)` then I don't think your description of `unlist` gives a clear description of what `unlist(A)` would return.

Comment: @42, I agree with you. OP states his lists only contain one element though, so I've been specific on this occasion.

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer I've updated my solution. Maybe that clears things up a bit more?